# Access VBA OutPutTo to PDF

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

I am using the following code:

```
 DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "ReportName", acFormatPDF, fileName, False
```

I need the output pdf to fit in one page and view page horizontal. Now I am getting vertical and 3 pages.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize your report so that it fits on one page, and set the page orientation of the report to Landscape...

To set the Page layout, goto Print Preview, then click Page Setup on the Ribbon, adjust the page Orientation, and save the report.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to use the following code and have the same result.

Comment: DoCmd.OutputTo acForm, "FormName", acFormatPDF, FileName, False

Comment: Output the form and fit in one page.